# taylor series for cosx around 0

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

[image: example]
Hey, I have the following limit, and I would like to know if it's possible to use the maclaurin series for cos(x) around 0.
Is it okey to do the step I have done in the picture bellow?
and let's say I would have liked to get the series for x->2, is it possible to use the same maclaurin series for cos(x) again for x->2 ??
Thanks.

Comment: Why should you need the Taylor expansion for $\lim_{x\to0}\cos(xe^x)$? The function is continuous, so the limit is $\cos0=1$.

Comment: it is a part of a larger limit containing a few expressions from this type...

Comment: Please state the problem, then; and possibly use MathJax or try and type it as you can.

Comment: I just wan't to know if its possible to write the cosx function I have written in the picture the way I did using Taylor expansion.

Comment: Yes, of course it is.

Comment: And if I had to calculate this exact same limit, but this time when x->2 could I use the same Maclaurin series for cosx? or does it work only when x->0 ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, when you build a Taylor series around a given value of the variable $x$, you want to approximate locally the functionyou are considering.

This means that, around $x=0$, I should have developed to whole thing arriving so to

$1 - x^2 / 2 - x^3 - 23 x^4 / 24 - x^5 / 2 - x^6 / 720 + ...  $

In the same spirit, if you want to analyze your function around $x=a$, the result would be something like

$A0 + A1 (x -a) / 1!  + A2 (x - a)^2 / 2! + ...$

For your case,

$A0 = Cos[a E^a]$

$A1 = - (1 + a) Sin[a E^a] E^a$

$A2 =  - E^a ((1 + a)^2 E^a Cos[a E^a] + (2 + a) Sin[a E^a])$